# Django - Updating a value of a field every 24 hour automatically

Tags: django

I have the following model in my django project:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    player_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    ...
    player_lifetime = models.IntegerField(default=100)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['creation_time']
```

So, the Player instance gets the lifetime value 100 during its creation. Now, I want to update the value of this field every 24 hour by subtracting it with -10. After 1 day, this value should be 90, after the second day it should be 80 and so on.

How, can I let Django update this value for me automatically/periodically ?

Comment: Implement a cronjob to update it?

Comment: Ok, never heard of it. But I will look at it. Thanks for hint.